# How can I open a tab with a specific view selected

Tags: tab

I would like to have an commandLink which will link to the cases tab but will open it with a specific view displayed.
Is that possible? 
Is there a way to tell the tab to open showing a specific view?

Answer (score 1):

Please replace ListId with Id of listview to display on visualforce page.Lets name the below page as AccountListView

```
<apex:page>
<apex:enhancedList type="Account" height="300" rowsPerPage="10" id="AccountList"     listId="00BE0000003WyhN"/>
 </apex:page>
```

---

Lets say this is your extension class.Add accountlistview page to the pagereference.

```
public with sharing class myextension {

public myextension(Account controller) {

}

public pageReference callAnotherPage(){

    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/accountlistview');
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
 }
}
```

---

Lets say this is your actual page

```
<apex:page controller="Account" extensions="myextension">
<apex:form>
<apex:commandlink action="{!callAnotherPage}" target="_blank">
        <apex:commandButton value="Switch"/>
</apex:commandLink>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```